# Did Maxim Gorky say “You must write for children the same way you write for adults, only better”?

Tags: quotes

[Goodread's quote site](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/39024-you-must-write-for-children-the-same-way-you-write), attributes this quote to [Maxim Gorky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxim_Gorky):

> “You must write for children the same way you write for adults, only better.”

Did he say or write this (or a Russian equivalent)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably not.

Besides Maxim Gorky this phrase is misattributed to S. Marshak and K.Chukovsky (both are famous Soviet children writers).

An [answer to a very similar question](https://touch.otvet.mail.ru/question/36390752) (Russian text) provides a snippet from the book [Цитаты из всемирной литературы от Гомера до наших дней](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3572215/) (which translates as "Qutations of World Literature").

[image]

This snippet explains the author of the phrase is the son of [Vasily Yan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Yan) who used it in the preface to his father's 1969 book, Повести.

It explains it is a rephrasing of [Stanislavski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Stanislavski)'s phrase:

> Для детей нужно играть так же, как для взрослых, но только - лучше
>
> You must play for children the same way you play for adults, only better, more delicate, more  cultured, more perfect.

Comment: the last quote should be "для детей нужно играть так же, как для взрослых - только лучше"

Comment: @shabunc Yes. Corrected.